# Implementing Proxy RADIUS server

Tags: proxy, rules, radius, freeradius

I have a proxy RADIUS server and a Home RADIUS server to perform WPA2 authentication. The proxy server forwards all the requests to the Home server, which then performs authentication of the clients.

My question - Is it possible for the Proxy RADIUS server to filter the requests (based on some rules) before forwarding them to the Home AAA?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, see man rlm_attr_filter, you want to insert the module call into the pre-proxy section.

Comment: Another question - Can we write rules in such a way that the proxy drops/rejects the Access-Request messages based on some pre-defined policies from the client before forwarding them to the Home server/AAA?

Comment: Yes.

`client <id> {

}`

sections can contain arbitrary config items, which can be queried in the policy.

`client <id> {
    drop_if_foo = yes
}`

`authorize {
    if (("%{client:drop_if_foo}" == 'yes') && <other condition>) {
        reject
    }
}`

or if you don't want to respond

`authorize {
    if (("%{client:drop_if_foo}" == 'yes') && <other condition>) {
        handled
    }
}`